# Defined a function which asserts object fields are non-nullable but not work, how to fix it?

Tags: typescript

I defined a function in TypeScript like this:

```
export function assertsNotNil<T extends object>(
  obj: T
): asserts obj is {
  [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]>;
} {
  const nilFields = Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key, value]) => isNil(value))
    .map(([key]) => key);
  if (nilFields.length) {
    throw new Error(`Some fields of the object are nil: ${nilFields.join(',')}`);
  }
}
```

I want to use it to assert some types are actually non-nullable so I don't need to check again later:

```
const data: string | null = 1+1 === 2 ? "abc": null;

assertsNotNil({data});

console.log(data.toUpperCase())
```

But it doesn't work as I expected:

[image]

Where is wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: Not a solution, but if you disable `strictNullChecks` tsconfig option, the error goes away. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5k40W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts checked by your assertion are known to the compiler when data members are accessed via object passed into the type assertion function:

```ts
const data: string | null = 1+1 === 2 ? "abc": null;
const obj = {data};
assertsNotNil(obj);

console.log(data.toUpperCase());      // ERROR, 'data' is possibly 'null'

console.log(obj.data.toUpperCase());  // OK

const {data: dataAlias} = obj;
console.log(dataAlias.toUpperCase()); // OK
```